# Field allignment with error labels

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, label

I am looking for possible solutions that could be used to make our forms look better when displaying errors.

Our application is using Government of Canada Intranet Theme (WET 4) with bootstrap. The image below is an example of one of our many forms in this application.

We are looking to see what other peoples thoughts were on this as we have considered a lot of ideas but can't agree on anything.

Is there a better way to design the flow of these fields so that when there is errors on the page, fields don't look like they are all over the place at random.

[image]

Comment: There are so many HTML themes built with bootstrap that you can choose from

Comment: One way is, use popover (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) in bootstrap to display the error message. This way, the controls won't lose their alignment. If you want the users to see error messages per section, display them under Notes in Contact Information / Address section separately.

Comment: Unfortunately we are stuck with this template.
The popover is an interesting idea, but with accessibility still being a concern I'm not sure how that would play into it.. any suggestions/links?